# Typescript: recursive check nestest arrays

Tags: arrays, typescript, recursion, nested

i have problem looping through a nested array that can contains arrays of itself... that should represent a dynamic menu as follow:

this is how the objects are made:

```
Interface IMenuNode:

export interface IMenuNode {
    title: string;
    haveChildren: boolean;
    id: string;
    node: Array<IMenuNode>;
    link: string;
    img: string;
    value: string;
}

Class DataNode that implements IMenuNode

export class DataNode implements IMenuNode {
    title: string;
    haveChildren: boolean;
    id: string;
    node: Array<IMenuNode>;
    link: string;
    img: string;
    value: string;


userMenu: Array<IMenuNode>;
```

Now i have some informations in the MenuData as follow:

```
const MenuData: Array<IMenuNode> =
    [
        new DataNode('Menu 1', true, 'menu1', [
            new DataNode('SubMenu 1', true, 'submenu1',[
                new DataNode('SubSubMenu1', false ,'subsubmenu1', null, "/", "pathSelectorIcon.png"),
                new DataNode('SubSubmenu2', false, 'subsubmenu2', null ,"/", "pathSelectorIcon.png"),
            ]),
            new DataNode('Menu 2', true, 'menu2', [
            new DataNode('SubMenu 1', true, 'submenu1',[
                new DataNode('SubSubMenu1', false ,'subsubmenu1', null, "/", "pathSelectorIcon.png"),
                new DataNode('SubSubmenu2', false, 'subsubmenu2', null ,"/", "pathSelectorIcon.png"),
            ]),
```

How can i loop the entire MenuData (even recursively) and dynamically build a new menu (userMenu) based on some conditions
to choose which items (menu and submenu) the new menu should have of?

Comment: Which type of conditions will you be using to filter the new userMenu?

Comment: Hello, i should check if the current user have a certain role that match with the id property of IMenuNode. If so, then the menu or the submenu should be added to the userMenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below apparently do what you expect, hope it helps.

```
userMenu = newUserMenu(MenuData);

function newUserMenu(original: Array<IMenuNode>): Array<IMenuNode> {
    const newMenu: Array<IMenuNode> = []
    for (let menu of original) {
        if (User.hasAccess(menu)) { // Or other conditions

            // To ensure new reference
            // Note not passing the children, it must pass through recursive method below
            const newNode = new DataNode(menu.title, menu.haveChildren, menu.id, null, menu.link, menu.img, menu.value);
            newMenu.push(newNode);
            if (newNode.haveChildren) {
                newNode.node = newUserMenu(menu.node);
            }
        }
    }
    return newMenu;
}
```

I've edited your class and interface too, to ensure that the construction works like the example.

```
interface IMenuNode {
    title: string;
    haveChildren: boolean;
    id: string;
    node?: Array<IMenuNode>;
    link?: string;
    img?: string;
    value?: string;
}

class DataNode implements IMenuNode {

    constructor(
        public title: string,
        public haveChildren: boolean,
        public id: string,
        public node?: Array<IMenuNode>,
        public link?: string,
        public img?: string,
        public value?: string,
    ) { }
}
```

Edit: new example validating the children before adding current level on new menu.

```
// The new function only add the "dir" menus if they have children where the user have access
function newUserMenu2(original: Array<IMenuNode>): Array<IMenuNode> {
    const newMenu: Array<IMenuNode> = [];
    for (let menu of original) {
        if (User.hasAccess(menu)) {// Or other conditions
            // To ensure new reference
            // Note not passing the children, it must pass through recursive method below
            const newNode = new DataNode(menu.title, menu.haveChildren, menu.id, null, menu.link, menu.img, menu.value);
            if (newNode.haveChildren) {
                newNode.node = newUserMenu2(menu.node);
            }
            // Note, only add the menu if it has a link or if it "stores" a menu that the user has access and that has a link
            if (Array.isArray(newNode.node) && newNode.node.length > 0 || newNode.link) {
                newMenu.push(newNode);
            }
        }
    }
    return newMenu;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The code works, but i'm not able give submenu access (or not) to users. If i put an if statement at (if (newNode.haveChildren)... as example, the program get stuck.

    if (newNode.haveChildren) {
        newNode.node = newUserMenu(menu.node);
    }

I would like to check if the currentUser have the permission to access the current menu.id or to the submenu.id menu...

Comment: @AmiStack If the program stuck it's probably because of a infinite recursive call.
You should validate the permission only of the current level of the menu, and let the recursive call `newNode.node = newUserMenu(menu.node);` validate the next level... If in some way, you have to validate children first, to decide if the current menu should be added, than the code would be a little different. But to help I need to understand better what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What could be resulting in a infinite recursive call, it's a circular reference between menus... eg: `menu1 -> submenu1 -> subsubmenu1 -> menu1`. That will make it run indefinetly. Or even a mistake of calling `newUserMenu()` again to the current level, instead of the children.

Comment: @AmiStack I've added a new example where the children is validated before the current level.

Comment: Thank you again. The first example works fine. I haven't tried the second example, yet.

Comment: What if i want to pass to the function another parameter such as "MenuTitle" and search through all MenuData and it's submenu. Then if the menu is found is pushed to the newMenu array. It is possible a function like this?

Comment: @AmiStack For sure it is... Just make sure you pass the paranter to all the subsequent calls. And i suggest to use the second example as base, as it verify children before the current level. Any help needed just let me now.

Comment: Thank you JDuwe. It's possible to write an e-mail or it is possible to chat?

Comment: @AmiStack Hi, sorry for the delay, i'm a little off these days, but surely we can chat, you mean stackoverflow chat? Or something else? If there a way to send you my email address, not being here, that would be an option too.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my delay too. Don't know if there's a way to realtime chat on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my delay too. Don't know if there's a way to realtime chat on stackoverflow - my e-mail is amiblit at gmail dot com