# Remove items from nested arrays not corresponding to specific criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, nested

i would like to remove items from nested arrays (looping recursively) keeping only specific items (or subitems) that are present in a separate list (a simple string array).
Maybe the splice method can be used, returning the final array when all the unnecessary items or subitems have been removed.

Thank you very much.
Language: javascript/typescript
Code is very similar to another question i asked:

[Typescript: recursive check nestest arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838567/typescript-recursive-check-nestest-arrays/58841944?noredirect=1#comment104124760_58841944)

````
```
Interface IMenuNode:

export interface IMenuNode {
    name: string;
    child: boolean;
    id: string;
    node: Array<IMenuNode>;
    link: string;
    img: string;
    value: string;
}

Class DataNode that implements IMenuNode

export class DataNode implements IMenuNode {
    name: string;
    child: boolean;
    id: string;
    node: Array<IMenuNode>;
    link: string;
    img: string;
    value: string;


userMenu: Array<IMenuNode>;
```

```
const MenuData: Array<IMenuNode> =
    [
        new DataNode('Menu 1', true, 'menu1', [
            new DataNode('SubMenu 1', true, 'submenu1',[
                new DataNode('SubSubMenu1', false ,'subsubmenu1', null, "/", "Icon.png"),
                new DataNode('SubSubmenu2', false, 'subsubmenu2', null ,"/", "Icon.png"),
            ]),
            new DataNode('Menu 2', true, 'menu2', [
            new DataNode('SubMenu 1', true, 'submenu1',[
                new DataNode('SubSubMenu1', false ,'subsubmenu1', null, "/", "Icon.png"),
                new DataNode('SubSubmenu2', false, 'subsubmenu2', null ,"/", "Icon.png"),
            ]),
```
````

UPDATE:
Have arranged this function:

```
stripMenu(original: Array<IMenuNode>, menuItem: Array<string>) {
    const newMenu: Array<IMenuNode> = []
    original.forEach(function (menu, index) {
      console.log(index); console.log(menu);
      const newNode = new DataNode(menu.title, menu.haveChildren, menu.id, null, menu.link, menu.img, menu.value);
      if (menu.method !=null || menu.method !=undefined && menuItem.indexOf(menu.method) < 0){

        //if (menuItem.indexOf(menu.method) > -1) {
              menu.method=null;
          //}
        }else{
          if (menu.haveChildren) {
            console.log("The menu node is: " + JSON.stringify(menu.node));
            return (this.stripMenu(menu.node, menuItem);
          }
        }
    });

    return newMenu; // not populated at the moment.
}
```

Problem is that i get an error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'stripMenu' of undefined. This is due the use of forEach. If i use the for (let menu of original) the problem disappear but i have no index to splice any eventual menu children (if array). I can only do menu.method=null;

Comment: Can you give us an example of data at least ?

Comment: Try [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @AmiStack: People are willing to help.  But you need to supply a bit more: sample input, requested output, and ideally your attempts to do this yourself with how it failed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet i posted a sample data.

Comment: That's an improvement.  But we still don't know what you might want to remove: Is it specific ids?  Is it some text in the name?  Does it have to do with their icons?  Something else?  Also, is your output structure the same as your input, only with some nodes missing?  If you remove all the children from a parent, would you expect the parent to remain?

Comment: Thank you for the new update.  It's hard to know for sure, but it looks as if `stripMenu` is a plain function and not a method of your object.  If that's right, then it makes sense that `this.stripMenu` yields an error.  If you just change it to `return stripMenu(menu.node, menuItem);` does it fix the problem?

Comment: @Scott Sauyet " If you just change it to return stripMenu(menu.node, menuItem); does it fix the problem?" no, it doesn't . Already tried this. The problem is using array.forEach... If i use for (let menu of original) {...} the problem disappear.

Comment: Another alternative would be to save a reference to `this` -- sometimes called `self` in your function before the call to `forEach`, then just use `self.stripMenu...`.  But I think the suggestions from my answer are cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't really speak Typescript, so the following may involve a bad guess or two, but it should offer some help in any case.

We can write a generic `filterRecursive` function which takes a predicate function and the name of the child property to descend into (often `"children"`, here `"node"`) and returns a function which takes an array of objects with a recursive structure and returns a new version which keeps only those nodes which match the predicate.

Then we can build a function to do what you want to do on top of this.  I'm guessing that you want to remove by id, but this could easily be changed for other scenarios.  Our predicate simply says that the list of items to delete does not contain the current id.  Our `descend` property is just `node`.

This snippet shows that in action:

```js
const filterRecursive = (pred, descend) => (arr) => 
  arr .reduce (
    (res, child, _, __, {[descend]: kids, ...rest} = child) => pred (child)
      ? [...res, {...rest, [descend]: filterRecursive (pred, descend) (kids)}]
      : res, 
    []
  )

const removeMenuItems = (items, menu) => filterRecursive (
  (item) => ! items .includes (item .id),
  'node'
) (menu)


const menuData = [
  {name: 'Menu 1', id: 'm1', node: [
    {name: 'Submenu 1-1', id: 'm1-1', node: [
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-1-1', id: 'm1-1-1', node: [], link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-1-2', id: 'm1-1-2', node: [], link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},      
    ]},
    {name: 'Submenu 1-2', id: 'm1-2', node: []},
    {name: 'Submenu 1-3', id: 'm1-3', node: [
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-3-1', id: 'm1-3-1', node: [], link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-3-2', id: 'm1-3-2', node: [], link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},      
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-3-3', id: 'm1-3-3', node: [], link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},      
    ]},
  ]},
  {name: 'Menu 2', id: 'm2', node: [
    {name: 'Submenu 2-1', id: 'm2-1', node: []},
    {name: 'Submenu 2-2', id: 'm2-2', node: [
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 2-2-1', id: 'm1-3-1', node: [], link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 2-2-2', id: 'm2-2-2', node: [], link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},      
    ]},    
  ]},
  {name: 'Menu 3', id: 'm3', node: []}
]

console.log(
  removeMenuItems (['m1-3-2', 'm1-3-3', 'm3'], menuData)
)
```

This version ignores your `child` boolean property.  If you really need to update this to `false` for those ones that no longer have children, then I would not try to use the generic `filterRecursive` function and fold the two together into a single bespoke function.

The other thing to note is that this version includes an empty array (rather than, say, `null`) for the descendants node.  We could change this, and return `null`, or not include the descendants node at all in that case, but it's hard to figure out a generic approach that would serve everyone.

Again, I've made several assumptions that may not be warranted, and I haven't even attempted to convert this to Typescript, but I think it should at the very least help point you in the right direction.

---

### Update

Here is another version without much commentary, one which offers more control over how to get at your descendants (passing a function rather than a property name), but also requiring you to decide how to put back together your object.  With this version we can keep your `child` property intact, and use `null` for the `node` property when there are no children.  It's a bit more work, but also more powerful:

```js
const filterRecursive = (pred, getChildren, reconstruct) => (arr) => 
  arr .reduce (
    (res, child) => pred (child)
      ? [...res, reconstruct (child, filterRecursive (pred, getChildren, reconstruct) (getChildren (child) || []))]
      : res, 
    []
  )

const removeMenuItems = (ids, menu) => filterRecursive (
  (item) => ! ids .includes (item .id),
  (item) => item.node,
  ({node, child, ...rest}, children) => ({
    ... rest, 
    child: children .length > 0, 
    node: children.length > 0 ? children : null
  })
) (menu)


const menuData = [
  {name: 'Menu 1', child: true, id: 'm1', node: [
    {name: 'Submenu 1-1', child: true, id: 'm1-1', node: [
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-1-1', child: false, id: 'm1-1-1', node: null, link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-1-2', child: false, id: 'm1-1-2', node: null, link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},      
    ]},
    {name: 'Submenu 1-2', child: true, id: 'm1-2', node: null},
    {name: 'Submenu 1-3', child: true, id: 'm1-3', node: [
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-3-1', child: false, id: 'm1-3-1', node: null, link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-3-2', child: false, id: 'm1-3-2', node: null, link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},      
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 1-3-3', child: false, id: 'm1-3-3', node: null, link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},      
    ]},
  ]},
  {name: 'Menu 2', child: true, id: 'm2', node: [
    {name: 'Submenu 2-1', child: true, id: 'm2-1', node: null},
    {name: 'Submenu 2-2', child: true, id: 'm2-2', node: [
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 2-2-1', child: false, id: 'm1-3-1', node: null, link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},
        {name: 'SubSubmenu 2-2-2', child: false, id: 'm2-2-2', node: null, link: '/', icon: 'Icon.png'},      
    ]},    
  ]},
  {name: 'Menu 3', child: false, id: 'm3', node: []}
]

console.log(
  removeMenuItems (['m1-3-2', 'm1-3-3', 'm3'], menuData)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting code. Studying a possible implementation. Since i have an array with the menu or child menu to preserve, i would like to have a function that strip all the unnecessary menu. This seems to be doable. About typescript, all javascript code works fine (sometimes with little adjustment) since typescript is a javascript superset.

Comment: What I meant about Typescript is simply that I don't bother with it.  I can read it and, when absolutely required, write it.  But the benefits it offers never seem to me to be worth the overhead it imposes.  But if I'm interested in answering a TS question, I usually convert the code into plain JS first before proceeding.  That might leave the conversion back to you.